# Opening a file with a string

Tags: c

I'm working on a problem that requires me to adjust the name of a file and then create a new file using the adjusted name. I'm storing the adjusted name in an array called nameHolder[]. I'd like to use nameHolder, which contains "file.txt" as the name of the new file. The code I have is the following:

```
void createNewFile(char nameHolder[])
{
    
    FILE* myNewFile = fopen(nameHolder, "r");

    fprintf("****************%s******************", nameHolder);

    fclose(myNewFile);
}
```

I get NULL for myNewFile and I believe this is due to "file.txt" not existing in the directory, but the problem requires that I create an entirely new file that doesn't already exist.

Comment: The first argument to [`fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be a `FILE *`. Is this your actual code? Does your compiler not warn you about this?

Comment: Then you need something else than `"r"` for the second argument. Check the `fopen` documentation.

Comment: See: [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) "File access flags".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the man page:**

*RETURN VALUE*

> Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen(), and freopen()
> return a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

For a file to be read, it should exist, which doesn't in your case. `fopen` returns `NULL` on failure, you should check for it.

**Unrelated:**

The prototype of `fprintf` is:

```
int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

The first argument should be a `FILE *`, remedy it.

Answer (score 0):

You create a file, truncate it present like this:

```
FILE *myNewFile = fopen(nameHolder, "w");
```

Otherwise you want the mode "a" (or "a+").